# Should there be a comma after this adverbial phrase?

Tags: commas, dependent-clause, comma-splices

> From the moment I saw him I knew this wouldn't work out.

OR

> From the moment I saw him, I knew this wouldn't work out.

It just doesn't seem to flow as well in the second version. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a clause, but an adverbial phrase. According to most style guides, the comma is optional after an introductory adverbial phrase, but it is more often included than not.

Comment: Adverbial phrase! Let me change the question. Thanks so much.

Comment: I see. I'd definitely forgotten what it was actually called (and what it actually was). Thanks!

Comment: @eveline: Thanks for accepting my answer! And welcome to the site. P.S. You could also vote my answer up, if you think it is right...it's the round grey arrow above the number "0".

Comment: My personal rule is that an introductory phrase of more than three words gets a comma; fewer than three words, no comma; exactly three words, judgement call.  The example sentence justifies the rule: the comma makes it [much easier to parse.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It is not a clause: it merely contains a clause. Conversely, *when she appeared from the palace* is not a prepositional phrase, even though the most salient information arguably comes from the embedded prepositional phrase..

Comment: @eveline: As for whether or not to use the comma, see Shoe's answers [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119016/why-should-i-put-comma-after-a-dependent-clause/119022#119022) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37856/do-you-need-a-comma-before-a-subordinating-conjunction-like-if/37867#37867); largely the same considerations apply for adverbial phrases as for adverbial clauses.

Comment: Have corrected, and done a minor edit on your answer so that I could adjust voting. I was modelling on 'After I saw him' rather than 'From that moment ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Great! I would indeed treat *after...* as an adverbial clause, pace H&P.

Comment: @Cerberus I HAVE LIKE 13 REPUTATION POINTS AND THE THING WON'T LET ME CLICK. I've been trying to vote it up since the moment you answered. Hahah.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Checked those out--helped a lot!

Comment: @eveline: Oh, haha, well, it doesn't matter anyway. Thanks for trying!